# Rating multiple items at once - looking for examples and ideas

Tags: tables, ratings

I'm looking to present users with a data table of items to be **rated** on a scale of 1-5, or **rejected** (e.g. marked "Not Interested").

Basically, I'm envisioning a table of rows like:

`|ITEM NAME           [1][2][3][4][5]  X |`

I can't find any good-looking examples of such tables where lots of items are presented to be rated at once.  Does anyone know of any?   Do you know the name for this type of widget---'multi-item rating table'?

Answer (score 1):

If multiple items are to be rated at once, a grouping of items could be useful. In the [Ultimate guide to table UI patterns](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/ultimate-guide-to-table-ui-patterns/) the author describes the concept of table sections:

> When you need to group related rows you can consider using table sections (or table grouping). A section is a part of the table that groups related data. All groups shares same set of columns. For example, in a table that shows list of countries, regions are natural way to group rows. Each section should be styled differently and can be collapsible/expandable. Under each section you can show summarized data, if needed.

For each section there is a row containing summarized information. At this point you can add a rating widget for the section. The rating should be applied to all items of the section. The individual ratings should become visible when the user expands the section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Facebook does a good example of this when offer users a chance to rate places they have been (as per their location history). The present the user with three vertically stacked cards, with the title and location of the business, as well as 5 greeted out stars. When the user hovers over a star, I highlights the previous stars up to that point (hover on the fifth star, four stars light up). They also allow the user to 'close' a particular location and not rate it, with a small greeted out X in the top right, which once clicked presents a new location.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not useful to think of this in "widget" or "rating table" terms... these are developer elements not users view of the world.

Users have "entities that may want to rate". LinkedIn does an interesting "Person X. Do they have skill Y?"  UI.  A rating version of this could show current rating or a rating UI on hover over.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTAFYx.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below one and sorry I didn't got time to create a sample for showing visually.

Table Row:-

1. Take a icon on left side of row followed by title of item.
2. On right side you could keep star or number (1 to 5) or a drop down list (1 to 5) for rating purpose.
3. Below the rating you could provide a check box followed with text "Not Interested".
4. If a user tap on check box of "Not interested" then change the highlight color of row (similar to showing as if the row is disabled).

Hope, this helps you out !!!

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a simple survey. A lot of survey engines on the web do a great job with survey UX. Just visit Surveymonkey or Survs or any other leading survey engine and see how they do it. Google forms is also a must.